# Storing json (facebook api) in database & retrieve them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, facebook, koala

I've been storing some data from facebook api using koala gem in database :

```
fb_data = graph.get_connections(...)
fb_data.each do |t|
    obj.raw_data = t
    obj.save
end
```

and it looks like that when I extract it from database :

```
--- id: '111222333444' from: name: James B id: '44444333332222' story: XXX ...
```

It's not a format I familiar with, thus I was wondering if I did something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the answer, I found with the help of @miguelgraz :

```
fb_data = graph.get_connections(...)
fb_data.each do |t|
    obj.raw_data = YAML::dump(t) #Serialize the hash
    obj.save
end
```

and then, to retrieve data :

```
t = YAML::load(t) #deserialize it
```

Comment: I was about to say that you'd probably need to work with this hash in the `|t|` variable, glad to see you already found the proper solution =)

Comment: Thanks, asking me to check the class of `|t|` made me find the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably saving it in its raw format indeed, try using something like `t.to_json` to save a json of this info, maybe something like

```
fb_data = graph.get_connections(...)
fb_data.each do |t|
  obj.raw_data = t.to_json
  obj.save
end
```

Comment: Just tried that and now the result  looks like that : {\"id\":\"111222333444\",\"from\":{\"name\":\"James B\",\"id\":\"44444333332222\"},\"story\":\"XXX\", ... } but it's still not an array and I cannot access it. For example, if I try obj["id"], it returns "id" isntead of "111222333444"

Comment: You probably want something like a hash to be saved in the DB, right? Can you post the current format/state of the `fb_data` variable and the `|t|` iterator?

Comment: If I do ".class.name", `fb_data` returns "Koala::Facebook::API::GraphCollection" and `|t|` returns "Hash"